# Nemo-like file manager for Windows 8.1/10?

Tags: gratis, file-management, windows-8

I've been using Linux (Mint) for a while, and really like the overall look of the [Nemo file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager)). Is there a similar replacement for Windows 8.1? Preferably freeware.

The main features I want are the overall look (the top and sidebar) and the tabbed browsing.

Here is the overall look i want to replicate:
[image: Nemo file manager]

I would use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) in order to use it, but it's only in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

- imo the best, but shareware, so please pay for it is you use it, is [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/)
  [image]

  - a reasonable clone, which is free for commercial use is [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/index.php?lang=eng)
- there is also [Free Commander](https://freecommander.com/en/summary/)
- or, you could pay for the extremely configurable [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/) which I remember using on my Commodore Amiga 20 years ago! (it has been updated since then :-))

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Nemo I know only one Explorer alternate [Tablacus Explorer](https://tablacus.github.io/explorer_en.html).
*A tabbed file manager with Add-on support.*
Tablacus is Freeware too.

Answer (score 0):

Another good Windows file explorer that provides tabbed browsing and other features is Explorer++: https://explorerplusplus.com/.